# Configure JMS queue destination through java code

Tags: java, jboss, jms

I want to use JMS for in my application. But the requirement is I can not touch JBoss, means I have to configure queue/topic destination through java.
as I have to give destination as:

```
Queue myQueue = (Queue) initialContext.lookup("destination");
```

I can configure it in jBoss's -service.xml, but I need to do it by java coding only. How can I do it.
please suggest.
Thanks.

Comment: That's actually a HornetQ question...

Comment: JMS is a specification, with many implementations. JMS itself doesn't support configuration, you need to use an implementation specific API to configure it.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstand the question. Just to clarify, JMS it's just a JavaEE Specification (like JDBC), and HornetQ is the JBoss Implementation of it (which runs in JBoss AS). Anyways, I don't think your problem is related specifically to HornetQ.

Comment: BUT... if you need to use the HornetQ API in order to do that, it doesn't natively support dynamic queues.

Comment: @ EvertonAgner : i just want a destination , in my java code. how can i get it. as when i run my project on JBOSS AS, it gives javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: destinatione not bound

Comment: Ok, my point is that the JMS tool may need it to be configured. If you want to use a Queue that's not configured, you want a dynamic queue, which some JMS implementations doesn't support. But maybe the JBoss AS can make some voodoo in order to make it work.

Comment: See the first comment in this link and see if it helps... http://jaitechwriteups.blogspot.com/2006/08/how-to-create-queuetopic-in-jboss.html

Comment: Romi; Which version of JBoss are you using ?

Comment: @Nicholas: am using jboss-eap5.1

Answer (score 0):

Your sample line of code performs a JNDI API lookup of the previously created queue called "destination" and assigns it to a Queue object. So, you should configure that queue in JBoss environment or use default [preconfigured destinations](http://docs.jboss.org/jbossmessaging/docs/guide-1.0.1.SP5/html_single/index.html#conf.preconf.destinations), but need to change the name (and is not an scalable solution).

Comment: JuanZe: i couldnot find Pre-configured destinations in my jboss server. am using jboss-eap5.1

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your jboss version, but you can embed a hornetq-jms.xml that includes your queues/topics, doesn't need to be configured on the server already.  If you're looking at AS7, then you would need to configure.